# Trying to import RXCardLayout

Tags: java, import

Trying to import import GUI.layouts.RXCardLayout; but it can't be resolved. It is an extension of CardLayout that someone made and I found it online. Anyone know what the right import is?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about this [RXCardLayout](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/31/card-layout-focus/).

There are no special imports. It doesn't use a package. You just add the source to you project and compile the source code into your class path.

Maybe the problem is you need to add a package statement to put the code into the same package as your other source code.